# Screen share toolbar not showing in localhost, chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, localhost, screensharing

Once we start screen sharing on chrome browser we get screen sharing toolbar at the bottom of the screen with "Stop sharing" blue button on it.

[image]

The problem which I'm facing is when I debug the application in chrome, the above toolbar is not appearing but the toolbar showing in the live website.

I tried `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-` to make my connection as secure but the toolbar is not showing.

Comment: Can you try using HTTPS (as localhost only uses HTTP) ?